# Clarification on input

Tags: python, calculator

I was using code from someone else to make a compounding interest calculator in python. My question is on the second input "n" it asks for a string, but wants an integer and it gives no examples on how to answer the question. What should I put if the interests are compounded daily?

```
P = int(input("Enter starting principle please. "))
n = int(input("Enter Compound interest rate.(daily, monthly, quarterly, half-year, yearly) "))
r = float(input("Enter annual interest amount. (decimal) "))
t = int(input("Enter the amount of years. "))

final = P * (((1 + (r/(100.0 * n))) ** (n*t)))

print ("The final amount after", t, "years is", final)
```

Comment: *"I was using code from someone else"* - you will either need to ask that someone-else, or look up the [mathematical formula for compound interest](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_interest#Calculation) to make sense of it yourself. Either way, that is not really a programming question.

Answer (score 1):

```
P = int(input("Enter starting principle please. "))

n_str = input("Enter Compound interest rate.(daily, monthly, quarterly, half-year, yearly) ")
n_lookup = {"daily":356, "monthly":12, "quarterly":4, "half-yearly":2, "yearly":1}
n = n_lookup.get(n_str, 0)

r = float(input("Enter annual interest amount. (decimal) "))
t = int(input("Enter the amount of years. "))

final = P * (((1 + (r/(100.0 * n))) ** (n*t)))

print ("The final amount after", t, "years is", final)
```

Check out a demo [here](https://ideone.com/I0714d)

Comment: So I did this, but when I put 365 for daily, the final value I get is 0

Comment: My answer was more about "how do you go from the string 'daily/monthly/etc' to having a number. I did not check the actual formula. I would suggest you use a debugger to step through the code and check where it goes wrong.